# app keeps crashing , Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics

I am creating a game where random objects fall in random places and there is a ball with a fixed y-axis and keeps moving along the x-axis , and it has to move throw the objects , and i am trying to count the scores and the way i do it is i created a physics object and it is places in the same y-axis as the ball , and when the objects collide the score function should be called and increment the score by 1, but for some reason the app keeps crashing and it gives me this error.

```
2015-07-13 01:23:17.242 WalkRun[26792:3773366] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'shortwall' (60 x 60)] position:{30, 768} size:{60, 60} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001073c33f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001092eabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001073c332d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   SpriteKit                           0x0000000107ebfaf6 -[SKNode addChild:] + 111
    4   WalkRun                             0x00000001071c8c44 _TFC7WalkRun9PlayScene10leftObjectfS0_FT_T_ + 2868
    5   WalkRun                             0x00000001071c7ddc _TFC7WalkRun9PlayScene10randObjectfS0_FT_T_ + 236
    6   WalkRun                             0x00000001071c8102 _TToFC7WalkRun9PlayScene10randObjectfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000107a39fd4 __NSFireTimer + 83
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010732b4e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010732b0a5 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072ee3dd __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072eda06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e7569f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108046550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    14  WalkRun                             0x00000001071d54ce top_level_code + 78
    15  WalkRun                             0x00000001071d550a main + 42
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109ad9145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

and this is my code:

```
//
//  PlayScene.swift
//  WalkRun
//
//  Created by naeim on 7/10/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 naeim. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

    var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
    var wall = SKNode()
    var wallRight = SKNode()
    var wallMiddle = SKNode()
    var ballSpeed = CGFloat()

    var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
    var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")

    var ballGroup:UInt32 = 1
    var objectGroup:UInt32 = 2
    var gapGroup:UInt32 = 3

    var gameOver = 0

    var movingObjects = SKNode()

    var score = 0
    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x80d9ff)
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-9,0)

        self.addChild(movingObjects)

        //creating the ball
        ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + self.ball.size.height * 2)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.ball.size.width / 2)
        ball.zPosition = 10


        //let the ball rotate forever
        ballSpeed = 3
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(ballSpeed, duration: 1)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction)
        ball.runAction(repeatAction)
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballGroup
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = objectGroup
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = objectGroup

        self.addChild(ball)

        //creating the wall of the left
        wall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame),CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
        wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(2, self.frame.size.height * 2.0))
        wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
        self.addChild(wall)

        //creating the wall of the right
        wallRight.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
        wallRight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(2, self.frame.size.height * 2.0))
        wallRight.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        wallRight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
        self.addChild(wallRight)

        //creating the middle wall that objects pass by
        wallMiddle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
        wallMiddle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
        wallMiddle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        wallMiddle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = gapGroup
        wallMiddle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gapGroup
        wallMiddle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = objectGroup
        self.addChild(wallMiddle)

        //creating the label
        scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
        scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 70 )
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)

        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("randObject"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        var timerObjects = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("checkObjectPlace"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

    func checkObjectPlace(){



    }

    //function to randomly choose which object

    func randObject(){
        if gameOver == 0{

        var rand = arc4random_uniform(6)+1

        switch(rand){

        case 1:
            leftObject()
        case 2:
            middleObject()
        case 3:
            rightObject()
        case 4:
            LeftAndMiddleObject()
        case 5:
            rightAndLeftObject()
        case 6:
            rightAndMiddleObject()
        default:
            println("error !! non a number other than 0, 1, 2 has been choosen .")

            }

        }
    }

    //function to create the left objects

    func leftObject(){
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
        if rand == 1
        {

             bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + bigWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))

            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup

            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)

        }
        else
        {

            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup


            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
        }


    }

    //function to create the middle objects

    func middleObject(){

        var rand = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
        if rand == 1
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)
        }
        else
        {
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
        }

    }

    //function to create the right objects

    func rightObject(){
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
        if rand == 1
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - bigWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)

        }
        else
        {
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)

            if ball.position.x == tallWall.position.x{
                scoreIncrement()
            }
        }


    }

    //function to create a right and left object

    func rightAndLeftObject(){

        var rand = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
        if rand == 1
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - bigWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
             movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)

                        bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - bigWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
        }
        else
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - bigWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)
        }


    }

    func rightAndMiddleObject(){

        var rand = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
        if rand == 1
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))

            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])

            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)

        }
        else
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])

            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)
        }


    }

    func LeftAndMiddleObject(){

        var rand = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1
        if rand == 1
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))

            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])

            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)

        }
        else
        {
            var bigWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shortwall")
            var tallWall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tallwall")
            bigWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            tallWall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + tallWall.size.width / 2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))

            var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
            var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])

            tallWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
            tallWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: tallWall.size)
            tallWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigWall.size)
            bigWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            bigWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            tallWall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
            movingObjects.addChild(tallWall)
            movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)
        }


    }

    func scoreIncrement(){

        score = score + 1
       scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        println("contact")

        if  contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == gapGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == gapGroup {

            println("gap contact")

        } else {

            gameOver = 1
            movingObjects.speed = 0

        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if gameOver == 0 {

        ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(70,0))

        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {



    }
}
```

Comment: Use different names for class and method variables. bigWall, tallWall are class variables so do not use same variable names for initializing new instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests you are trying to add a child to a node while it already has a parent. The stack trace points you to leftObject method. In here you have an SKAction setup to move over a time interval and then remove from parent.

```
        var moveObjects = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.height / 100))
        var removeObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        var moveAndRemoveObjects = SKAction.sequence([moveObjects,removeObjects])
        bigWall.runAction(moveAndRemoveObjects)
```

This adds the action to the node and it runs but your code path will continue down to

```
    movingObjects.addChild(bigWall)
```

almost instantly. Looks like a race condition where you think the code will wait until the action has finished running before continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

You have a instance property called bigWall and in most of your methods you create a local object called bigWall and add it to the scene. Since it is a new object each time the methods are call that works fine. However in the method leftObject you do not have a local object bigWall so it is referencing the instance property. The first time you call leftObject it will work fine adding your instance property bigWall to the scene. The second time you call the method it will try to add the bigWall instance property to the scene when it is already in the scene and that is where you will get the error.